# SingleTask activity fails to return result?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've encountered very strange Android behavior.

I have two activities, A and B. A starts B with `startActivityForResult` and then checks B's resultCode. It can be `RESULT_OK`, `RESULT_CANCELLED` or `RESULT_FIRSTUSER` . No matter how hard I tried, whenever I returned `RESULT_FIRSTUSER` from B, A saw `RESULT_CANCELLED`.

Out of desperation, I thought "Maybe it's because B is a SingleTask activity", so I modified the manifest and removed the `SingleTask` definition. This worked, now `RESULT_FIRSTUSER` is returned to A properly.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

startActivityForResult only work if the activity being launched is in the same task as the launching activity. Official document at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int, android.os.Bundle)

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you expect. For example, if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

Comment: That explains why I saw my Activity B get started twice, too!